# Getting RecylerView Item Position using another Listener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gesturedetector

I have a Listener to detect gesture in a RecycleView. It can detect Swipes and (supposedly) ItemTouch. I need the listener to be able to get position from an item on the RecycleView.

Here's the Listener code :

```
public abstract class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 200;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 200;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        onItemTouch(e.getX(), e.getY());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        onItemLongTouch(e.getX(), e.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 300;
        final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 500;

        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e1.getY() - e2.getY();
            float diffX = e1.getX() - e2.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                } else {
                }
                result = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}

public void onItemTouch(float x, float y) {
}

public void onItemTouch() {
}

public abstract void onTouch(View view, int i);

public abstract void onTouch(View view);

public void onItemLongTouch(float x, float y) {
}

public void onItemLongTouch() {
}
```

}

And here's the usage of the Listener on my Activity :

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouch(View view, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            Intent intentSettings = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, TrackingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentSettings);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);            }

        @Override
        public void onTouch(View view) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongTouch(float x, float y) {
        }
    });
```

If there's anything needed for the answer, just ask me.

Thank you :)

Comment: cannot you use `android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get position in onTouch Method using below code

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    int pos = view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView)
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Please use below code,I have created new class for detecting gestures.

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListenerTouchs implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
private OnItemClickListener mListener;
private int pos = -1;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    public void onItemClick(int position);
    public void onSwipeRight(int position);
    public void onSwipeLeft(int position);
}

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListenerTouchs(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            mListener.onItemClick(pos);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

        }
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 300;
            final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 500;

            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e1.getY() - e2.getY();
                float diffX = e1.getX() - e2.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            mListener.onSwipeRight(pos);
                        } else {
                            mListener.onSwipeLeft(pos);
                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

    });
}


@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null ) {

        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
        pos = view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}}
```

And in your activity implement `RecyclerItemClickListenerTouchs.OnItemClickListener`

and use listener with recycler view as `rvJobs.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListenerTouchs(MyJobsActivity.this, this));`

Hope this will help

Comment: should i put this at my Listener class or my Activity ?

Comment: @bravevctr your welcome, Please let me know if it works